# Conflict between lexer rules in ANTLR4 for Fortran grammar

Tags: parsing, fortran, antlr4, lexer

I'm developing a Fortran parser using ANTLR4, adhering to the ISO Fortran Standard 2018 specifications. While implementing lexer rules, I encountered a conflict between the `NAME` and `LETTERSPEC` rules. Specifically, when the input consists of just a letter, it is always tokenized as `NAME` and never as `LETTERSPEC`. Here's a partial simplified version of the grammer:

```
lexer grammar FortrantTestLex;

// Lexer rules
WS: [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip;

// R603 name -> letter [alphanumeric-character]...
NAME: LETTER (ALPHANUMERICCHARACTER)*;

// R865 letter-spec -> letter [- letter]
LETTERSPEC: LETTER (MINUS LETTER)?;

MINUS: '-';

// R601 alphanumeric-character -> letter | digit | underscore
ALPHANUMERICCHARACTER: LETTER | DIGIT | UNDERSCORE;

// R0002 Letter ->
//         A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H | I | J | K | L | M |
//         N | O | P | Q | R | S | T | U | V | W | X | Y | Z
LETTER: 'A'..'Z' | 'a'..'z';

// R0001 Digit -> 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9
DIGIT: '0'..'9';

// R602 UNDERSCORE -> _
UNDERSCORE: '_';
```

```
grammer FortranTest;
import FortranTestLex;

// Parser rules

programName: NAME;

// R1402 program-stmt -> PROGRAM program-name
programStmt: PROGRAM programName;

letterSpecList: LETTERSPEC (COMMA LETTERSPEC)*;

// R864 implicit-spec -> declaration-type-spec ( letter-spec-list )
implicitSpec: declarationTypeSpec LPAREN letterSpecList RPAREN;

implicitSpecList: implicitSpec (COMMA implicitSpec)*;

// R863 implicit-stmt -> IMPLICIT implicit-spec-list | IMPLICIT NONE [( [implicit-name-spec-list] )]
implicitStmt:
    IMPLICIT implicitSpecList
    | IMPLICIT NONE ( LPAREN implicitNameSpecList? RPAREN )?;

// R1403 end-program-stmt -> END [PROGRAM [program-name]]
endProgramStmt: END (PROGRAM programName?)?;

// R1401 main-program ->
//         [program-stmt] [specification-part] [execution-part]
//         [internal-subprogram-part] end-program-stmt
mainProgram: programStmt? endProgramStmt;

//R502 program-unit -> main-program | external-subprogram | module | submodule | block-data
programUnit: mainProgram;

//R501 program -> program-unit [program-unit]...    
program: programUnit (programUnit)*;
```

In this case, the tokenization always results in NAME even though it could also be a valid LETTERSPEC. How can I resolve this conflict in my lexer rules to ensure correct tokenization?

I've tried adjusting the order of the lexer rules and refining the patterns, but I haven't been able to achieve the desired behavior. Any insights or suggestions on how to properly handle this conflict would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Given that Fortran 2023 spec is paywalled, you might want to summarise what you are trying to do. Is it that names are always at least two characters (if they were one, they would be letterspec)? If so, maybe `NAME: LETTER ALPHANUMERICCHARACTER (ALPHANUMERICCHARACTER)*`?

Comment: Or `NAME: LETTER (ALPHANUMERICCHARACTER)+`? And try specifying `LETTERSPEC` *before* `NAME`.

Comment: @Amadan, the F2023 spec might be paywalled, but the document used by J3 for interpretations is available.  It is essentially the same doc, but with different formatting.

Comment: Hmm, looking at [J3 current draft standard N2209](https://j3-fortran.org/doc/year/23/23-007.pdf) #8.7, if this was *flex/yacc* I would be telling you to enter a START state at `IMPLICIT`. but I don't know ANTLR well enough to suggest a solution.

Comment: Name can be single character as well. Can I use 'mode' feature in antlr4 to resolve this issue.

Comment: Evidently it is only available in lexer mode, not lexer+parser mode which you are using.

Comment: @Amadan You can find Fortran 2023 specifications in the resources linked at the [tag:fortran] tag page. Namely, the link to [24-0007](https://j3-fortran.org/doc/year/24/24-007.pdf) at J3 should be relevant

Comment: Is this different than how older versions of Fortran handle things? You may have a look at how previous versions handle it: https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/tree/master/fortran

Comment: The last version available is Fortran90 and this conflict is not there in that grammer

Comment: I am not talking about the ANTLR grammar: I was wondering if what you are trying to implement also exists in the older Fortran version(s). If it already exists in the older version(s), then you can have a look at how this is handled in the older version(s) of the grammar(s).